# Error in Http Post

Tags: java, php, android, android-asynctask, http-post

I m beginner in android development and 
I'm using using [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) code and use it as a method to  post data in a url.
i call this method from a async task.

and show error in `HttpResponse`

error: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php`

php code:

```
$username = @$_POST['username'];
$password = @$_POST['password'];

$mysql_query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO  `android_connect1`.`user` ( `username` , `password` ) VALUES ( '$username',  '$password')");
```

Comment: wheres the java code?? and are you using localhost??

Comment: yes i'm using localhost.
Java code is in the link, open the link you will understand.

Comment: The example has two parameters but they are not named 'username' and 'password'

Comment: try to use "http://192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php" instead of "192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php"

Comment: then it should be something like 127.0.0.1 thats localhost in my case and make sure your xampp or wamp server is online

Comment: If you're using an emulator, to connect to the localhost, use 10.0.2.2 rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: i changed it as 'username' and 'password' in both java and php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a http host error.

use this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php");
```

instead of

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php");
```

Comment: i works but that code doesn't pass username, password in php.
you have any idea?

Comment: parameters problem is another problem. please make new question with user code.

Answer (score 0):

use single quote to query variable

```
$mysql_query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO  `android_connect1`.`user` ( `username` , `password` ) VALUES ( '$username',  '$password')");
```

or use `.`(dot) to concat instead of `+`

```
$mysql_query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO  `android_connect1`.`user` ( `username` , `password` ) VALUES ( '".$username."',  '".$password."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a problem in the syntax after VALUES (if only this code snippet is erroneous

```
 $username = @$_POST['username'];
 $password = @$_POST['password'];
 $mysql_query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO  `android_connect1`.`user` ( `username` , 
 `password` ) VALUES ( '"+$username+"',  '"+$password+"')");
```

> Try this

```
 $mysql_query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO  `android_connect1`.`user` ( `username` , 
 `password` ) VALUES ( '$username',  '$password')");
```

> Why were you using + here ..?? The variables $username and $password have got the values
>   which can be inserted into the DB by this simple query

Comment: i think error is not coming from any of the php codes or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL seems missing http:// try to add in prefix 192.168.56.1/android_connect/get_users.php

ex:- http://xxx.xxx.xx.x/android_connect/get_users.php